# Using calculated field to fill an email recipient, subject and body?

Tags: 2010, email, custom-form, calculated-column-formula, ie8

I am using calculating field to fill an email field and it does work perfectly for the "recipient" field.

```
<Field
    ID="{BE6CFDC4-07CF-4175-98E7-E82259A41B5F}"
    Name="myfieldInternalName"
    StaticName="myfieldInternalName"
    DisplayName="my field"
    ResultType="Text"
    Type="Calculated"
    Required="FALSE"
    Group="myGroup">
    <Formula>="mailto:" &amp; mailAdressInternalName</Formula>
    <FieldRefs>      
      <FieldRef Name="mailAdressInternalName"/>
    </FieldRefs>
```

When I'm clicking, it shows me an outlook "new email" page with the recipient field already filled with the mail adress. (It has probably been setting up to do that). That's OK.

[image]

Now I want to the other fields to be filled too. (i.e. Subject and Body).
How do I do that please ?

Answer (score 0):

You are only using `mailto:` in you code, that means it is the Browser that formats the link, and some browsers won't

It is better to set the ResultType to Number and create a full HTML element

```
 ="<a href=""mailto:'"& [Email] & "?subject=xxx&body=yyy'"">"
```

Details for formatting the url:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782068/can-i-set-subject-content-of-email-with-using-mailto

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I really need to do it the way I did in my example. Plus I need to use other fields to fill the mail and not add a predefined content like you're doing in your example. The examples you linked use also a predefined content.